# Improve Battery when using GooglePlayService

Tags: android, service, background, google-play-services, battery

I using service from GooglePlay to get location.
But after apply service, battery  gone so fast.

Who can help me improve battery when using google-play-service.

My code locationservice.

```
public class LocationService extends Service implements
    GooglePlayServicesClient.ConnectionCallbacks, 
    GooglePlayServicesClient.OnConnectionFailedListener, LocationListener {

private static final String TAG = LocationService.class.getSimpleName();
public static final long TIME_LOC_PERIOD = 180000;

private LocationClient mLocationClient;

private static final LocationRequest REQUEST = LocationRequest.create()
        .setInterval(180 * 1000) // 1 phut
        .setFastestInterval(60 * 1000) // 15 seconds
        .setPriority(LocationRequest.PRIORITY_HIGH_ACCURACY);

@Override
public void onCreate() {
    Log.d(TAG, "Creating..");
    mLocationClient = new LocationClient(this, this, this);
}

@Override
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
    Log.d(TAG, "Starting..");
    if (!mLocationClient.isConnected() || !mLocationClient.isConnecting()) {
        Log.d(TAG, "Connecting location client..");
        mLocationClient.connect();
    }
    return START_STICKY;
}

@Override
public void onConnectionFailed(ConnectionResult result) {
    Log.d(TAG, "Connection failed..");
    stopSelf();
}

@Override
public void onConnected(Bundle bundle) {
    mLocationClient.requestLocationUpdates(REQUEST, this);
}

@Override
public void onDisconnected() {
    Log.d(TAG, "Disconnected..");
    stopSelf();
}

@Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent arg0) {
    throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not yet implemented");
}

@Override
public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
    updatePosition(location.getLongitude(), location.getLatitude(), location);
}

@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    Log.d(TAG, "Destroying..");
    mLocationClient.removeLocationUpdates(this);
}

private void updatePosition(...)
```

}

And code call service in activity

```
if (!isLocationServiceRunning() && isGooglePlayServiceAvailable()) {
        Intent service = new Intent(GlobalInfo.getInstance()
                .getAppContext(), LocationService.class);
        startService(service);
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The trick is here in your code

```
private static final LocationRequest REQUEST = LocationRequest.create()
    .setInterval(180 * 1000) // 1 phut
    .setFastestInterval(60 * 1000) // 15 seconds
    .setPriority(LocationRequest.PRIORITY_HIGH_ACCURACY);
```

change the priority to not high accuracy,  also,  update interval to longer

look at this link.  will give you some ideas.  Its a trade between battery and accuracy in the end

http://blog.lemberg.co.uk/fused-location-provider